# SELinux is not supported with the overlay graph driver

Tags: docker, centos, kubernetes, kubectl

When I installed docker and ran `service docker start` I got this message:

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When I ran `journalctl -xe` I got this message:

```
8月 02 20:42:11 centos-master systemd[1]: Unit docker-storage-setup.service entered failed state.
8月 02 20:42:11 centos-master systemd[1]: docker-storage-setup.service failed.
8月 02 20:42:11 centos-master systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has begun starting up.
8月 02 20:42:11 centos-master dockerd-current[32672]: time="2017-08-02T20:42:11.667102874+08:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 32676"
8月 02 20:42:11 centos-master dockerd-current[32672]: time="2017-08-02T20:42:11.681065709+08:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver \"overlay\""
8月 02 20:42:12 centos-master dockerd-current[32672]: time="2017-08-02T20:42:12.045251482+08:00" level=fatal msg="Error starting daemon: SELinux is not supported with the overlay graph driver
8月 02 20:42:12 centos-master systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
8月 02 20:42:12 centos-master systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
```

thanks my friends

Comment: i find config file in /etc/sysconfig/docker . and i add` DOCKER_OPTS="--storage-driver=devicemapper" ` and delete  OPTIONS='--selinux-enabled --log-driver=journald --signature-verification=false'    it's ok  why?

Comment: Because different OS have different storage drivers available. Read this https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/

Answer (score 27):

Docker version 1.13.1

For CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core), ensure following `DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS` option is set to `devicemapper`.

```
bash # vi /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage
...
DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS="--storage-driver devicemapper "
...

bash # vi /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage-setup
...
STORAGE_DRIVER=devicemapper
...
```

Comment: Thanks @Praveen! Changing the files worked! 
Just to add a bit. You need to do the obvious step `sudo systemctl restart docker` after it.

Comment: While this is a quick god-sent fix, the reason is in the next answer, which is docker 1.13 being only compatible with the storage "devicemapper" not "overlay2" on CentOS. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [compatibility matrix](https://success.docker.com/article/compatibility-matrix) docker-1.13 for CentOS supports only `devicemapper`.

Got a similar problem with docker trying to start by default with `overlay2`, solved downgrading to docker-1.12.